# Cloudformation how to Sub inside of a ImportValue inside of a Sub?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I feel I have tried just about every combination for this to work, and have come up empty handed. Has anyone done this? I am trying to reference an import value inside of a sub while referencing the the parameter ApiStack. Appreciate any advice!

```
LambdaPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt MyLambdaFunction.Arn
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Sub 
                    - arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${ApiGateway}/*/POST/CreateBofAParameter
                    - ApiGateway: !ImportValue 
                        'Fn::Sub': '${ApiStack}--APIID'
```

Answer (score 2):

The same to used in the question code structure worked for me, thus, as mentioned in the comments, the issue is not related to **Sub** / **ImportValue** precedence or format.

```yaml
  Arn: !Sub
    - "arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:access-point/${VariableToImport}"
    - VariableToImport: !ImportValue
        'Fn::Sub': "${SubVariable}-some-id"
```

Answer (score -1):

You have extra `'`. It should be:

```
'Fn::Sub': "${ApiStack}--APIID"
```

Comment: Err I think that was a typo inputing it into here. I've updated the comment to reflect what I have. Does it matter if it is a ' or "?

Comment: @Jamills102 It shouldn't matter. Double check other "typos" as your code is fine now. There is no reason it would not work. So maybe your code in your question  is not a correct representation of your actual code.